# How to render a component on each route with working functionality?

Tags: reactjs, rendering, router

I'm trying to render a component that plays an mp3 on each route, and have the mp3 continue to play uninterrupted despite route changes.  I'm not sure if this is possible, but i'd assume it is considering React creates single page sites.

So far i've only gotten as far as getting the component to render, my problem is all of the functionality along with the component has seized to work... I can't figure out why..

```
 <HashRouter>
        <Route path="/" render={props => <Music />} />
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
        <Route path="/work" component={MyWork} />
        <Route path="/about" component={About} />
  </HashRouter>
```

The Route in question is the first one. 
I've also tried this thinking I needed to pass down the props in order for the functionality to work

```
        <Route path="/" render={props => <Music
          changePlayingState={props.changePlayingState}
          playing={props.state.playing}
          showMusicMessage={props.showMusicMessage}
          hideMusicMessage={props.hideMusicMessage}/>} />
```

A working version of the component(and how i would like it to appear on all routes) is shown on the home page(click play) code sandbox had a file size limit so i just added some popping sound effects(takes a second to start playing)

https://codesandbox.io/s/rlw1q45m1m

The only components regarding this question (and the only you'll need to view)are as follows:

Index.js

The routes: Home.js, About.js, MyWork.js

Music Component: Music.js

If any additional information is needed please ask! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You just have to pull out the Music Component and make it a stand alone Component in itself then pass it down to the `HashRouter` within a single child and rest of the `Routes`.

Here is an [example](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/sidebar) to implement `NavBar` in each route of the React App.